# WPF Textbox accept INT but not NULLABLE INT?

Tags: c#, wpf, int, nullable

Model

```
public int? SizeLength { get; set; }
```

XAML

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding [someViewModel].SizeLength, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
```

Once user try to <kbd>backspace</kbd> or <kbd>delete</kbd> the value in this `textbox`, a message `Value '' cannot be converted`.

May I know what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use:

```
{Binding TargetNullValue=''}
```

Comment: I tried `<TextBox Text="{Binding [someViewModel].SizeLength, Mode=TwoWay,TargetNullValue='0'}"></TextBox>` as well as `<TextBox Text="{Binding [someViewModel].SizeLength, Mode=TwoWay,TargetNullValue=0}"></TextBox>`..Both still throwing the same error

Comment: @Mr.SuicideSheep - You need to set it to empty string as mentioned in answer and not to 0.

Answer (score 4):

Since the integrated converters from string to single/double/int of WPF are expecting a string to parse they won't default the null value to 0 because you won't always want that behavior, so as it is written in MSDN :

> Gets or sets the value that is used in the target when the value of
>   the source is null.

you use this to define your default value for null input:

```
{Binding TargetNullValue=''}
```

[TargetNullValue msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference of mscorlib in your XAML, Nullable or ? in your prop and use TargetNullValue  with value "" like Elios said.

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

public Nullable<int> Prop { get; set; }

{Binding prop, TargetNullValue=''}
```